# What does cc (file name).c -l(library's name) -o (output file name) do and why does it work when make doesnt?

Tags: c, import, include, cs50

I started getting into c programming and was following a series of lectures on the cs50 platform, due to some problems with my internet i decided it would make sense to download the library so i could work on the problem sets while offline, after downloading the library and including it in the project the make command wouldn't work at all giving me this output

> cc     main.c   -o main /tmp/ccz5QZev.o: In function `main':
>   main.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to`get_string' collect2:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status : recipe for target 'main'
>   failed make: *** [main] Error 1

get_string is defined on the #include "libcs50-develop/src/cs50.h", some one told me that running "cc main.c -lcs50 -o main" instead of "make" would solve the issue, the suggestion did work, but i wasn't able to contact the person again to find out why. could someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: Your `get_string` function may be *declared* in cs50.h, but it is not *defined* there, else you would not have the error you describe.  That is, the header does not contain the function's implementation, neither in source nor in binary form.  Apparently an implementation is included in a library named libcs50 that your system knows about; the `-lcs50` compiler argument says to get the implementation from there.  The relationship of header name to library name is merely convention, and by no means universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invokation is performing two steps, the compilation and the linking.

The error you are getting is from the linking step when the linker is attemping to bind the symbols declared in the header cs50.h

There must be a library file that also needs to be included in the compilation.

That seems to be the advice you received and I agree. The problem might be that the linker needs to know where the library "cs50" resides in the path.

That is typically indicated in a further switch to the linker to tell the linker where the libraries are located.

For the gcc compiler one indicates the directories to search for the library using the -L switch. [(see options)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Comment: `cs50.h` is a header, not a library.  You include headers in source files.  You include libraries on the linking command line.  They're radically different. One is plain text and human readable; the other is object code and only machine readable.  The header and the library are related, of course, because there's one or more C source files (usually) that implement the functions declared by the header, and those source files are compiled to object code and a library is created from the result.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, cs50.h is indeed a header and not a library. Fixed